# Taking a snapshot from webcam during using the camera in anther function

Tags: python, linux, opencv, image-processing, camera

I am using the camera to detect cars 24/7 using Python, Opencv and a normal usb webcam. 
In order to take a snapshot I made a function to call it when needed

```
def SendPic () :
    capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
    img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    cv.SaveImage('pic.jpg', img)
```

It works fine when used alone but when used inside my code this error comes up

```
libv4l1: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable to ioctl VIDIOCSPICT
```

And the image is not saved or even captured

How to take this snapshot without stopping the camera from detecting the cars? What command can I use to stop the camera to take a capture and then return to its main function?

Comment: why you are using `cv`? Please use updated versions of opencv!

Comment: so, you already got a capture loop running *besides* above function ? (and yes, please move over to cv2, the old cv one won't be supported in upcoming opencv versions)

Comment: maybe all it needs is a flag in your *existing* capture loop: 'now save this image'.

Comment: I guess a flag may help ,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I was You, I'd make the part taking pictures a separate module, and make the car detection module and snapshot module call to the first one using mutexes. You cannot have two separate entities controlling the same hardware piece.